# Can I use the cost of a query to prove its efficiency when there is only a small number of rows?

Tags: oracle, performance, execution-plan, query-performance

Can I run `EXPLAIN` (Oracle) for a query when there is only a few dozen rows in the table and use the cost to prove whether the query is efficient or not ?

Can you measure the efficiency of a query when there is only a little data in the table(s) ?

I have a query that someone else wrote and I would like to know if it's not going to have a negative impact.

The query has multiple nested sub queries, uses subqueries with `substr()` to populate one column.

```
SELECT /* disasterHistorySQL.getDisasterHistoryList */ * 
  FROM (
                SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY DISASTER_DATE DESC, SEQ DESC ) AS RNUM ,  
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY DISASTER_DATE ASC , SEQ ASC ) AS LNUM ,
                       TYPE_NM_LEVEL1,
                       TYPE_NM_LEVEL2,
                       TYPE_NM_LEVEL3,
                       DISASTER_DATE,
                       CAUSE_NM_LIST,
                       DISASTER_AREA,
                       AREA_DETAIL,
                       DISASTER_LAT,
                       DISASTER_LONG,
                       DISASTER_TYPE,
                       DISASTER_CAUSE,
                       HUMAN_DEATH,
                       HUMAN_INJURY,
                       HUMAN_MISSING,
                       HUMAN_REFUGEES,
                       DAMAGE_AMT,
                       DAMAGE_ETC,
                       DISASTER_FLOW,
                       RELATED_LAW,
                       MANUAL,
                       REG_ID,
                       REG_DATE,
                       UPD_ID,
                       UPD_DATE,
                       DISASTER_NM,
                       SEQ,
                       NVL( ATTACK_A , 'X' ) AS ATTACK_A,
                       NVL( ATTACK_B , 'X' ) AS ATTACK_B,
                       NVL( ATTACK_C , 'X' ) AS ATTACK_C,
                       NVL( ATTACK_D , 'X' ) AS ATTACK_D,
                       NVL( ATTACK_E , 'X' ) AS ATTACK_E,
                       NVL( ATTACK_F , 'X' ) AS ATTACK_F,
                       NVL( ATTACK_G , 'X' ) AS ATTACK_G,
                       NVL( ATTACK_I , 'X' ) AS ATTACK_I,
                       BJC_NAME
                  FROM (
                              SELECT ( SELECT CATEGORY_NM 
                                         FROM TB_DISASTER_TYPE_CATE 
                                        WHERE CATEGORY_ID = SUBSTR( DISASTER_TYPE , 0 , 5 ) ) AS TYPE_NM_LEVEL1,
                                     ( SELECT CATEGORY_NM 
                                         FROM TB_DISASTER_TYPE_CATE 
                                        WHERE CATEGORY_ID = SUBSTR( DISASTER_TYPE , 0 , 8 ) ) AS TYPE_NM_LEVEL2,
                                     ( SELECT CATEGORY_NM 
                                         FROM TB_DISASTER_TYPE_CATE 
                                        WHERE CATEGORY_ID = DISASTER_TYPE ) AS TYPE_NM_LEVEL3,
                                     (
                                        SELECT WM_CONCAT(category_nm)
                                          FROM TB_DISASTER_CAUSE_CATE a
                                         WHERE REGEXP_LIKE ( a.category_id ,  DISASTER_CAUSE  ) 
                                     ) AS CAUSE_NM_LIST,
                                         TO_CHAR( TO_DATE( disaster_date , 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI' ) , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ) AS DISASTER_DATE,
                                         ( SELECT ATTACK_TYPE FROM TB_DISASTER_HISTORY_ATTACK WHERE SEQ = MAIN.seq AND ATTACK_TYPE = 'A' 
                                           group by ATTACK_TYPE ) AS ATTACK_A,
                                         ( SELECT ATTACK_TYPE FROM TB_DISASTER_HISTORY_ATTACK WHERE SEQ = MAIN.seq AND ATTACK_TYPE = 'B' 
                                           group by ATTACK_TYPE ) AS ATTACK_B,
                                         ( SELECT ATTACK_TYPE FROM TB_DISASTER_HISTORY_ATTACK WHERE SEQ = MAIN.seq AND ATTACK_TYPE = 'C' 
                                           group by ATTACK_TYPE ) AS ATTACK_C,
                                         ( SELECT ATTACK_TYPE FROM TB_DISASTER_HISTORY_ATTACK WHERE SEQ = MAIN.seq AND ATTACK_TYPE = 'D' 
                                           group by ATTACK_TYPE ) AS ATTACK_D,
                                         ( SELECT ATTACK_TYPE FROM TB_DISASTER_HISTORY_ATTACK WHERE SEQ = MAIN.seq AND ATTACK_TYPE = 'E' 
                                           group by ATTACK_TYPE ) AS ATTACK_E,
                                         ( SELECT ATTACK_TYPE FROM TB_DISASTER_HISTORY_ATTACK WHERE SEQ = MAIN.seq AND ATTACK_TYPE = 'F' 
                                           group by ATTACK_TYPE ) AS ATTACK_F,
                                         ( SELECT ATTACK_TYPE FROM TB_DISASTER_HISTORY_ATTACK WHERE SEQ = MAIN.seq AND ATTACK_TYPE = 'G' 
                                           group by ATTACK_TYPE ) AS ATTACK_G,
                                         ( SELECT ATTACK_TYPE FROM TB_DISASTER_HISTORY_ATTACK WHERE SEQ = MAIN.seq AND ATTACK_TYPE = 'I' 
                                           group by ATTACK_TYPE ) AS ATTACK_I,
                                         (
                                                   SELECT SI_NAM ||' '|| GU_NAM AS BJC_NAME
                                                     FROM TB_BJDCODE_2014
                                                    WHERE BJC_CDE LIKE MAIN.DISASTER_AREA||'%'
                                         ) AS BJC_NAME ,
                                         DISASTER_NM,
                                         DISASTER_AREA,
                                         AREA_DETAIL,
                                         DISASTER_LAT,
                                         DISASTER_LONG,
                                         DISASTER_TYPE,
                                         DISASTER_CAUSE,
                                         HUMAN_DEATH,
                                         HUMAN_INJURY,
                                         HUMAN_MISSING,
                                         HUMAN_REFUGEES,
                                         DAMAGE_AMT,
                                         DAMAGE_ETC,
                                         DISASTER_FLOW,
                                         RELATED_LAW,
                                         MANUAL,
                                         REG_ID,
                                         REG_DATE,
                                         UPD_ID,
                                         UPD_DATE,
                                         SEQ
                                    FROM TB_DISASTER_HISTORY MAIN
                       )
                WHERE TO_CHAR( TO_DATE( disaster_date , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ) , 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) BETWEEN #start_date# AND   #end_date#

                    <isNotNull property="search">
                    <isNotEqual property="search" compareValue="">
                        AND DISASTER_NM || TYPE_NM_LEVEL1 || TYPE_NM_LEVEL2 || TYPE_NM_LEVEL3 || CAUSE_NM_LIST LIKE '%$search$%'
                    </isNotEqual>
                    </isNotNull>

                    <isNotNull property="disaster_type_p">
                    <isNotEqual property="disaster_type_p" compareValue="">
                        AND DISASTER_TYPE LIKE '$disaster_type_p$%'
                    </isNotEqual>
                    </isNotNull>

                    <isNotNull property="disaster_cause_p">
                    <isNotEqual property="disaster_cause_p" compareValue="">
                        AND DISASTER_CAUSE LIKE '$disaster_cause_p$%'
                    </isNotEqual>
                    </isNotNull>

                     <isNotNull property="human_type">

                     <isEqual property="human_type" compareValue="human_death">
                        AND HUMAN_DEATH BETWEEN #human_value_min# AND #human_value_max#
                     </isEqual>

                     <isEqual property="human_type" compareValue="human_injury">
                        AND HUMAN_INJURY BETWEEN #human_value_min# AND #human_value_max#
                     </isEqual>

                     <isEqual property="human_type" compareValue="human_missing">
                        AND HUMAN_MISSING BETWEEN #human_value_min# AND #human_value_max#
                     </isEqual>

                     <isEqual property="human_type" compareValue="human_refugees">
                        AND HUMAN_REFUGEES BETWEEN #human_value_min# AND #human_value_max#
                     </isEqual>
                     </isNotNull>

                     <isEqual property="attack_a" compareValue="A">
                        AND ATTACK_A = #attack_a#
                     </isEqual>

                     <isEqual property="attack_b" compareValue="B">
                        AND ATTACK_B = #attack_b#
                     </isEqual>

                     <isEqual property="attack_c" compareValue="C">
                        AND ATTACK_C = #attack_c#
                     </isEqual>

                     <isEqual property="attack_d" compareValue="D">
                        AND ATTACK_D = #attack_d#
                     </isEqual>

                     <isEqual property="attack_e" compareValue="E">
                        AND ATTACK_E = #attack_e#
                     </isEqual>

                     <isEqual property="attack_f" compareValue="F">
                        AND ATTACK_f = #attack_f#
                     </isEqual>

                     <isEqual property="attack_g" compareValue="G">
                        AND ATTACK_G = #attack_g#
                     </isEqual>

                     <isEqual property="attack_i" compareValue="I">
                        AND ATTACK_I = #attack_i#
                     </isEqual>

       )
  WHERE RNUM BETWEEN #startNum# AND #endNum#
```

Looking at this query, I feel we should change the way the tables are referencing each other, architectured.
To do so, I feel that I need to prove that this is costly with a good evidence.
I may as well be wrong but I would like to know if the cost can reflect the efficiency of a query whether the table is small or big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not that easy, unless you notice some trivial mistake.

Cost is just an estimation. An estimation, based on statistics, that may be outdated or non-existent. Even if you have 100% up-to-date and accurate statistics, the optimizer will have a hard time with nontrivial queries, and it will make inaccurate estimates. Explain plan with bind variables makes it even worse - explain plan will simply ignore your histograms and assume that your data is evenly distributed for an equality filter, and it will estimate based on predefined rules for non-equality filters.

About the efficiency and small number of rows - unless you know your data and query well, also not. The database may choose a different access path, join order or join method based on the row sources. What works on a small scale, may not work well on a large scale.

If you want proof: test and evaluate. If you have a query, and you know the cost of its execution plan is 15957, you know nothing. If you know the amount of elapsed time, cpu time, disk io time, reads, gets, number of rows processed, executions, memory/tmp usage, etc. per step, those are some results that can serve as a baseline.